# What is the difference between the "start" and "start now" options in Transmission?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

In Transmission, if you right-click on a paused torrent, you will get a menu. One option is "Start" and the one below that is "Start Now".

[image]

Neither of these options have any tooltips associated with them, nor is there any information on the official webpage.

Comment: I believe if you have multiple things downloading and you click `start` it'll put it in the queue until a download spot opens up. If you `start now` it starts it even if all download spots are currently downloading. Just a guess, but makes sense

Comment: @Tim. He's talking about a torrent already opened in Transmission.

Answer (score 12):

I believe if you have multiple things downloading and you click `start` it'll put it in the queue until a download spot opens up. If you `start now` it starts it even if all download spots are currently downloading. Just a guess, but makes sense

Comment: sorry, I can't mark this as accepted w/o a cite

Comment: As you've already found there is no official documentation on this. I can only tell you this from personal experience having used Transmission for I can't even tell you how long

Comment: hmm. "Start" and "Start Now" both seem to cause a torrent to start downloading, regardless of how many active downloads are set (in my case 2) as I now have more than 2

Comment: Closest reference looks [this "Resume" and "Resume now"](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/5974) bug tickets. Maybe [this one too](https://trac.transmissionbt.com/ticket/5670). @TomH maybe on Transmission Preferences, Download queue, Maximum active downloads you have a number greater than 2.

Comment: looking at the source code ( https://github.com/transmission/transmission/blob/943b57979fafac416408ba50088b31e10404f76b/libtransmission/torrent.cc ), `tr_torrentStartNow(tor)` calls `torrentStart(tor, bypass_queue=true)` whereas normally they're started via `torrentStart(tor, bypass_queue=false)`, so the hypothesis suggested here seems to be the case (assuming the code works as designed). A normal "start" would just queue the torrent; but "start now" (i.e., `bypass_queue=true`) should start it immediately instead of waiting for a spot from another torrent going idle.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct, but to add, "Start Now" in transmission corresponds to "Force Start" on other torrent clients.
and if the first answer did not explain it well here is an example borrowed from

[quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Start-and-Force-Start-in-uTorrent?share=1)

> 1st scenario
>   Suppose I'm downloading 5 things in queues..
>   1. ABC  downloading
>   2. BCD Queued
>   3. ....
>   4. ....
>   5. ....
>   
> Now I want first two things downloaded once so what'll do is..
>   Right click on 2nd download and select "Force start".
>   By choosing "Force Download" the download will start immediately even if it is in queue..
>   
> Now 2nd scenario..
>   1. ABC  downloading
>   2. BCD Force-downloading
>   3. ....
>   4. ....
>   5. ....
>  
>   
> Now, again right clicking on 2nd download choosing the option "start" will again put my download in "queue"...
>   
> Sometimes it starts on its own when the 1st download is getting low speed, the application will start 2nd download simultaneously just to increase the downloading speed.